# C++, find_if with vector<unique_ptr> is not working properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I realize that similar questions has been asked before but i didn't find the answer to my question so I'm just gonna post it here.

`iteratorHelper` takes an `accountNr` as argument, searches a vector of unique_ptrs and returns a bool.

The problems is in the second method.

The if-statement in `getAccInfo(size_t pAccNr)` is giving me problems.
My IDE is complaining about the "`iteratorHelper`" saying that

> The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Client::iteratorHelper". Object type is const Client

I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing here so if anyone could point me in the right direction?

```
auto Client::iteratorHelper(size_t accountNr ) {
  return find_if(
    accounts.begin(), accounts.end(),
    [&accountNr ](const unique_ptr<Account>& account) {
      return account->getAccountNr() == accountNr;
    }
  );

unique_ptr<Account> const & Client::getAccInfo(size_t pAccNr) const {
  if (iteratorHelper(pAccNr) != accounts.end()) {
    auto const& index = distance(accounts.begin(), iteratorHelper(pAccNr));
    return accounts[index];
  }
  return nullptr;    
}
```

Comment: How can you find something that is unique?

Comment: Being new to C++, somehow that question doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Nothing to do with C++. Think about it: You're looking for something that only ever exists once. How would you know that you found it? You can't compare it with anything, because it is unlike anything else.

Comment: I cleaned up the code formatting, and noticed you are missing a `}`.  I am unsure if that is from your original code, or it was a transcription error.  Also, actually including the actual full error message and indicating what line it refers to is the least you can do when asking this kind of question.  You may think that your abbreviation is "all we need to know", but if you knew what was wrong *you wouldn't be asking here*.  [MCVE] means you generate the same error after making the code simpler, and post *the actual code that generates the error* and *the actual error*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iteratorHelper` is not `const`.  You are calling it from a `const` function `getAccInfo`.  This is illegal.